# Google Ads API request return as AUHENTICATION_FAILED error

Tags: google-api, postman, ads, google-ads-api

I want to use reporting HTTP endpoints for that I send a request with postman But every time I getting AUTHENTICATION_ERROR.

My oAuth2 response :

> {"token":{"access_token":"ya29.a0AfH6SMCyU5L******","refresh_token":"1//09Iryk6eZYKj0CgYIA********","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
> [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords","token_type":"Bearer","expiry_date":1624622265323}}](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords%22,%22token_type%22:%22Bearer%22,%22expiry_date%22:1624622265323%7D%7D)

I used "ya29.a0AfH6SMCyU5L******" as access_token for request header.

And my postman request like that:

[image]

Where did I make mistake? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why not let postman handle the auth?  https://youtu.be/jjCauMywU2Q

Answer (score 0):

You really should use the official client libraries that handle all of this. Reporting is explicitly not to be done via REST as they're expensive.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/best-practices/quotas

> Get requests Get requests (for example, using the GetCampaign method
> on the CampaignService), have daily usage limitations separate from
> the limits on operations, which are outlined in the Access Levels and
> Permissible Use guide. Unlike daily operations, the limits on get
> requests do not vary by access level; all developer tokens, including
> those with Standard Access, are limited to 1,000 get requests per day.
> Unlike search requests, get requests are expensive because all
> attribute data is retrieved. **Use search instead of get whenever
> possible.**

If you really need to use REST, please post your full code.